# How do I use a mapping variable to re-index a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, mapping

I have the following data frame:

```
                  population   GDP
country
United Kingdom    4.5m         10m
Spain             3m           8m
France            2m           6m
```

I also have the following information in a 2 column dataframe(happy for this to be made into another datastruct if that will be more beneficial as the plan is that it will be sorted in a VARS file.

```
county           code
Spain            es
France           fr
United Kingdom   uk
```

The 'mapping' datastruct will be sorted in a random order as countries will be added/removed at random times.

What is the best way to re-index the data frame to its country code from its country name?

Is there a smart solution that would also work on other columns so for example if a data frame was indexed on date but one column was `df['county']` then you could change `df['country']` to its country code? Finally is there a third option that would add an additional column that was either country/code which selected the right code based on a country name in another column?

Comment: Do you need to use a mapping variable to do this? Is the typo "county" intended.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), but it works only with `Series`, so need [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html). Last [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df1.index = df1.index.to_series().map(df2.set_index('county').code)
df1 = df1.rename_axis('county')
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df1.index.name = 'county'
print (df1)
       population  GDP
county                
uk           4.5m  10m
es             3m   8m
fr             2m   6m
```

It is same as mapping by `dict`:

```
d = df2.set_index('county').code.to_dict()
print (d)
{'France': 'fr', 'Spain': 'es', 'United Kingdom': 'uk'}

df1.index = df1.index.to_series().map(d)
df1 = df1.rename_axis('county')
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df1.index.name = 'county'
print (df1)
       population  GDP
county                
uk           4.5m  10m
es             3m   8m
fr             2m   6m
```

EDIT:

Another solution with [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html), so `to_series` is omitted:

```
d = df2.set_index('county').code.to_dict()
print (d)
{'France': 'fr', 'Spain': 'es', 'United Kingdom': 'uk'}

df1.index = df1.index.map(d.get)
df1 = df1.rename_axis('county')
#pandas bellow 0.18.0
#df1.index.name = 'county'
print (df1)
       population  GDP
county                
uk           4.5m  10m
es             3m   8m
fr             2m   6m
```

Comment: The third solution above is great. Is it possible to cast the `code` part below from a variable?

`d = df2.set_index('county').code.to_dict()`

so the line could be like this `d = df2.set_index(from_format).to_format.to_dict()`

where `from_format` and `to_format` are variables?

Comment: If `from_format` and `to_format` are `string` variables, then you can use: `d = df2.set_index(from_format)[to_format].to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some brief ways to approach your 3 questions. More details below:

1) How to change index based on mapping in separate df

Use [`df_with_mapping.todict("split")`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) to create a dictionary, then use a list comprehension to change it into `{"old1":"new1",...,"oldn":"newn"}` form then use `df.index = df.base_column.map(dictionary)` to get the changed index.

2) How to change index if the new column is in the same df:

`df.index = df["column_you_want"]`

3) Creating a new column by mapping on a old column:

`df["new_column"] = df["old_column"].map({"old1":"new1",...,"oldn":"newn"})`

**1) Mapping for the current index exists in separate dataframe but you don't have the mapped column in the dataframe yet**

This is essentially the same as question 2 with the additional step of creating a dictionary for the mapping you want.

```
#creating the mapping dictionary in the form of current index : future index

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["es"],["fr"]],index = ["spain","france"])
interm_dict = df2.to_dict("split") #Creates a dictionary split into column labels, data labels and data
mapping_dict = {country:data[0] for country,data in zip(interm_dict["index"],interm_dict['data'])}
#We only want the first column of the data and the index so we need to make a new dict with a list comprehension and zip

df["country"] = df.index #Create a new column if u want to save the index
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).map(mapping_dict) #change the index
df.index.name = "" #Blanks out index name
df = df.drop("county code",1) #Drops the county code column to avoid duplicate columns
```

Before:

```
       county code language
spain           es  spanish
france          fr   french
```

After:

```
   language country

es  spanish   spain
fr   french  france
```

**2) Changing the current index to one of the columns already in the dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["es","spanish"],["fr","french"]], columns = ["county code","language"], index = ["spain", "french"])
df["country"] = df.index #if you want to save the original index
df.index = df["county code"]  #The only step you actually need
df.index.name = "" #if you want a blank index name
df = df.drop("county code",1) #if you dont want the duplicate column
```

Before:

```
   county code language
spain           es  spanish
french          fr   french
```

After:

```
   language country

es  spanish   spain
fr   french  french
```

**3) Creating an additional column based on another column** 
This is again essentially the same as step 2 except we create an additional column instead of assigning `.index` to the created series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["es","spanish"],["fr","french"]], columns = ["county code","language"], index = ["spain", "france"])
df["city"] = df["county code"].map({"es":"barcelona","fr":"paris"})
```

Before:

```
       county code language
spain           es  spanish
france          fr   french
```

After:

```
       county code language       city
spain           es  spanish  barcelona
france          fr   french      paris
```